# Disable / Uninstall / Manage services from a list (Batch)

Tags: batch-file

Basically the way i worded this was kinda bad to start off. What i want to do is make a list of service names E.A- Fax or hns and many more and run a single script that runs that list and disables all of them using minimal lines of code as possible.

Example of what I want to use
hns
Fax
ftpsvc
SNMP
...

and then run a script that uses those lines and make it so that all on that list are disabled

My idea is that it sets the first line as a variable and then runs a command to disable it and then goes to the next line and disable the next one and go all the way down the list until all are done

basically this but question is, is there a way to repeat this without having to write the "set Service= _____" every time

```
set ServiceOff=sc stop %service% | sc delete %service%

set Service= Fax
%ServiceOff%
ser Service = Netlogon
%ServiceOff%
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a for loop as:

```
for /F %%I in (file.txt) do (
    sc stop "%%I" 
    sc delete "%%I"
)
```

Where file.txt is the file whith the desired service names.

Comment: Service names can have spaces so you need to enclose the for variable in quotes.